# Get list of dependencies for Ruby program

Tags: ruby, dependencies

I have a Ruby program that is part of a very large code base that I would like to extract and use elsewhere.

The program in question requires several other files that are in different directories, and those files in turn depend on several other files, and so on and so forth.

Is there a quick way that I can get a list of all the files this program depends on, and the directories they live in, so that I can just take the stuff I need?

I feel like there must be some way to see this if I load up the file in IRB, but I can't think of which method or module I might need for this kind of introspection. Googling has not helped much either.

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried? Just thinking aloud, I might `grep` for any instances `require` or `require_relative` in Ruby files, and iterate over those results with `find`.

Comment: Patch `require` (temporarily).

Comment: I tried tracing the program's execution with `ruby -r tracer myprogram.rb` but it created a huge file and it was difficult to get at the info with grep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options if you're open to heuristics.

#### Option 1: Unix find

- Are all the files within any kind of top level directory, such as "/foo/bar/"?
- Are you able to run just the Ruby program, not the rest of the large code base?
- If yes, then you can find all the directories and files that the Ruby program touches:

  ```
  find /foo/bar -atime -1
  ```
- An advantage of this option is that finds the Ruby code plus assets the program needs, such as css, images, javascripts, etc.
- A caveat: if the command doesn't turn up anything, then your file system may be caching the atime settings for a day; to learn more google "noatime".

#### Option 2: DTrace

- Similar to the -atime solution above, DTrace can profile a running application and report which files are accessed.
- An advantage of this option is that you get real-time results as the program runs, and you can attach to just the program process.

#### Option 3: Intercept Kernel.require

- If you're only interested in the Ruby code that runs, not interested in the assets, then you can intercept the Ruby file require method.

  ```
  module Kernel
    alias_method :old_require, :require

    def require(name)
      puts "requiring #{name}"
      old_require(name)
    end
  end
  ```
- An advantage of this solution is that it shows just the Ruby runnable files, not any of the the assets.
- An advantage is that you can extract the code ad-hoc using conditional logic. For example you can extract all items that contain "hello" into a different directory like this:

  ```
  def require(name)
    if name=~/hello/
      # Whatever logic you want goes here,
      # such as dynamically altering the load path,
      # or altering the name, or skipping the require.
    end
    old_require("#{my-original-location}/name")
  end
  ```
- A caveat of this solution vs. the other solutions above, is that you won't detect Ruby code that is loaded using atypical ways, such as using `File.read` then `eval`.

#### Advice

- If your app has a Gemfile, that's a good place to look for major dependencies.
- If your app uses git submodules, that's another good place to look.
- If your app has a test suite, be sure to run it so you get all the test suite files too.
- If your app has dynamically-required files, or files that are only loaded on some of the execution paths, you'll need to find them a different way than running the app; ideally your test suite will exercise all the dynamically-required files.
- If you don't have a test suite, or the suite isn't thorough, you may want to write some simple functional tests first. You don't need 100% test coverage to start, and you don't need to focus on unit tests; you just need enough of a smoke-test to detect if you accidentally break major functionality as you extract pieces.
- If your code is important, also search your codebase for any occurences of the `eval` method, `File` class, `IO` class, etc. What you're looking for is any kind of dynamic loading of code and/or assets.

Comment: This is a great answer! I was getting ready to give up on this, so it's prefect timing. I am able to run just the Ruby program, not the rest of the large code base, so I might try the find command first. Thanks.

Comment: @Adam Good, and thanks for the s/Class/Module/ edit.